# Vue parts of website not working after build

Tags: vue.js

I have the following problem, for example when I delete a user on my website it works in debug mode (npm run serve) but not in final build (npm run build).

Here it gives the message

> "TypeError: this.selectedMembers is undefined".

Here is a little code example:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import axios from "@/axios";
import { useModalStore } from '@/stores';
import { SearchIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/solid'


const selectedMembers = ref([])
</script>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ControlDashboardView',
    watch: {
        $route: {
            immediate: true,
            handler(to) {
                document.title = to.meta.title || this.$t('Members') + ' - sdf';
            }
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            members: [],
            slicedMembers: [],
            currentPage: 1,
            ItemsPerPage: 10,
            search: "",
        }
    },

    async created() {
        await this.getAllMembers();
        this.sliceMembers();
    },
    methods: {
        deleteSelectedMembers: async function (yes) {
            if (!yes)
                return;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedMembers.length; i++) {
                await axios.delete("user/delete-by-id/" + this.selectedMembers[i]);
            }

            this.selectedMembers = ref([])
            await this.getAllMembers();
            this.sliceMembers();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Does anyone know what exactly this could be?
Also several functions do not work in the production build.

Comment: `this.selectedMembers` is probably somewhere, doing some stuff. Hard to help you out with only that amount of context. Consider providing a [repro].

Comment: Now I've added @kissu

Comment: So your answer is 270 lines of code? Could you please make an effort and scope it down to only the relevant parts. Starting by, do you use Vue2 or 3? Did you thought about maybe securing some of your conditional, like `selectedMembers?.length` in case the left part is undefined/not an array?

Comment: @kissu sorry, I've edited. He throw the error in "DeleteSelectedMembers". in "this.selectedMembers.length". The curios thing is, it`s working fine in development mode.